# getComputedStyle returns unexpected z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css

When trying to get `computed style` of a element without position defined I get `auto`.

The unexpected part for me here is that the parent element has `z-index: 100;`

Should `getComputedStyle` return `100` for A1 or is `auto` the correct value (although `z-index` for A1's parent is > B)

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DJpY/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#A, #B {
    position: absolute;
}
#A {
    top: 35px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 35px;
    background-color: #999999;
    z-index:100;
}
#A1 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: #CC0066;
}
#B {
    top: 35px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 35px;
    background-color: #99CC00;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="A">
        <div id="A1">I am A1, on top of B.
            <br />My parent has z-index 100</div>
    </div>
    <div id="B">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />I am B and have no z-index. I
        <br />f I had `z-index:200;` A1 would not be visible</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var elementA1 =  document.getElementById('A1');
var a1 = window.getComputedStyle(elementA1).getPropertyValue("z-index");
console.log(a1); // logs 'auto'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `position: relative;` for #A1 in order to get proper value for z-index.

And if only #A element has the z-index, then #A1 should have also `z-index:inherit;`

I updated your fiddle and it now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/6DJpY/1/

See details: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15562#c13

Answer (score 2):

`auto` is correct, since the element itself doesn't establish a *new* stacking context and is at level 0 in the current stacking context, see [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index):

> ```
> auto
> ```
>
> The stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context is 0. The box does not establish a new stacking context unless it is the root element.

This means that relative to `A`, `A1` is one the same level, whereas `A1` relative to `container` is on 100:

```
#container    (level   0 in context 0)
    #A        (level 100 in context 0; new context 1)
        #A1   (level   0 in context 1; relative to #container: 100 via context 1)
    #B        (level   0 in context 0)
```