# Wait for all elements to have a z-index less than 2

Tags: cypress

I have a number of elements that are animating (manually by setting position in JS, not via CSS transforms), and I want to assert their position when they have all stopped.

The simplest way I have of determining if they are animating is that animating elements will all have a z-index of 2 (I'll refactor later to add `data-` attributes to make this more robust, but for now this is it).

In the Cypress docs it says that assertions will automatically wait until they pass, but that's not the behaviour I'm seeing:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getNumberOfMovingElements', () => {
  cy.get(`[data-test-element="square"]`)
    .then(squares => {
      const movingSquares = Array.from(squares).filter(square => square.style.zIndex === '2');
      return movingSquares.length;
    })
});


Cypress.Commands.add('getPosition', () => {
  cy
    .getNumberOfMovingElements().should('be.at.most', 0)
    .etc
```

This fails because when I call it, I have one moving square. How can I wait until the assertion is true?

Comment: I think the retry mechanism is not active within the `.then()`. You might find it works with `[...squares].forEach(sq => cy.wrap(sq).its('zIndex').should('not.eq', 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a `.then` is guaranteed to only be called once. A `.should` would retry, but would not change the subject.

A trick is to combine a `.should` with a `.invoke`:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getNumberOfMovingElements', () => {
  cy.get('.someclass')
  .should($el =>
    $el.fn = () => {
      return $el.toArray().filter(el => getZindex(el) === 2)
    })
  .invoke('fn')
})

const getZindex = (el) => {
  const doc = el.ownerDocument
  const zindex = doc.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el).zIndex

  return +zindex
}
```

We have to do this because `.invoke` can change the subject, but can only call method that exists on the subject (the cypress team is working on making this cleaner)

keep in mind the `getComputedStyle` method of getting a css property will take into account both stylesheets and inline styles. If you keep getting an `auto` `z-index`, [check this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629626/getcomputedstyle-returns-unexpected-z-index)

Edit: **personally I would refactor this for better re-usability** (you can call the function, or call the command off of cy):

```js
const getNumberOfMovingElements = () => {
  Cypress.log({ name: 'GET', message: 'getNumberOfMovingElements' })

  return cy.get('.someclass')
  .should($el =>
    $el.fn = () => {
      return $el.toArray().filter(el => getZindex(el) === 2)
    })
  .invoke('fn')
}

const getZindex = (el) => {
  const doc = el.ownerDocument
  const zindex = doc.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el).zIndex

  return +zindex
}

Cypress.Commands.addAll({prevSubject: false}, { getNumberOfMovingElements })
```